# run the roslaunch comman in Qt creator

Tags: ros, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to run the roslaunch command in Qt but the error is:

```
sh: 1: /opt/ros/indigo/bin/roslaunch/roslaunch: not found
```

and I tried to download the plugin for ROS it still doesn't work.

and here is my code:

```
QProcess * exec;
exec =new QProcess(this);
exec->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
//exec->start("gnome-terminal", QStringList()<<"source ~/catkin_ws/devel/settup.bash; roslaunch p2os_launch pioneer_joy_drive.launchS ")
QString command = "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roslaunch/roslaunch p2os_launch pioneer_joy_drive.launch";
exec->start(command);
system(qPrintable(command));
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248602/run-the-roslaunch-comman-in-qt-creator/) by [Nicky0201](https://answers.ros.org/users/28591/nicky0201/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried writing only "roslaunch" instead of "/opt/.../roslaunch"?

Dont known if it helps, but heres one solution for a similiar situation: [link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/209090/how-to-launch-a-roslaunch-in-qt-with-a-terminal-gui/)

---

Originally posted by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) with karma: 137 on 2017-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0